# Password hash : create another entity without re-hashing

Tags: php, symfony, hash, password-encryption

### Context

My application handles FTP accounts on a server, for several "global users" (each of them has several FTP accounts). When a user registers, he is given his first FTP account, with the same credentials as his global account.

For instance, if a user registers with **myusername** and **mypassword**, two entities will be persisted :

- The main account, with those credentials, and a salt.
- The first FTP account, which I'd like to have exactly the same credentials (same username, same password, same salt).

### Problem

I use a `postPersist` Doctrine event to create the **FTP account**. When a user registers (is persisted), the event automatically creates a **FTP account** entity associated to the user, with the same credentials. Here's a code sample from `postPersist` :

```
// $user is the entity passed through the event args ($args->getEntity()).
$ftp = new FTPAccount();
$ftp->setUsername($user->getUsername());
$ftp->setSalt($user->getSalt());
$ftp->setPassword($user->getPassword());
```

**Note :** both entities use the same password encoder, that's why copying the password hash and the salt is appropriate.

But here's the problem : Symfony considers `$user->getPassword()` as cleartext, and therefore rehashes it once the **FTP account** entity is persisted. This is due to this part of my `security.yml` file :

```
security:
    encoders:
        FTPAccount: sha512
```

Considering the following facts :

- I cannot get the user's cleartext password in `postPersist`, it's already hashed.
- I do not always have the hashed password (here, I have it because it is the first **FTP account**)

Is there a way I could ask Symfony to bypass password hashing for this entity instance ?

Comment: I don't know about symfony, but would it be possible to simply disable the password hashing completely in the settings and roll your own using something like [password_hash()](http://www.php.net/password_hash)? That way you should have complete control over when and how the password is hashed and also keep a variable of the plain text password to create another account using the same password. Besides, if all it's doing now is `sha512($salt.$password)`, that is very poor password hashing and you would benefit from hashing it yourself.

Comment: The fact is that Symfony uses a custom algorithm as `sha512` : it includes specific salts and iterations.

Comment: Just because something is made available, doesn't mean it's a good idea. Even if you are stretching it thousands of times (which doesn't appear to be the case), there are better algorithms than sha512 for password hashing. From the [manual](http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/security.html): "New in version 2.2: As of Symfony 2.2 you can also use the PBKDF2 and BCrypt password encoders." If you're going to use one of the built-in algorithms, I would highly recommend using one of those instead.

Comment: Basically it doesn't really solve the problem, to change the algorithm, I'd still declare it in my security file, and re-hashing would occur. In the end it doesn't matter whether I use sha512, PBKDF2 or md5, in the problem's context.

Comment: I realize that, that's why I mentioned rolling your own password hashing thing using `password_hash()` which would allow you to do whatever you want with the plain text password in the meantime. Just make sure you don't store it in plain text.